# swift play Audio with byteStream

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

I have a bytestream from a udp server and want to play it no my iphone. 
But i cant find any solution to play bytes. The only suggestion is, play directly from URL but in my case this is impossible.

Any suggestions to play a byteArray in swift?

Comment: Check this one out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340738/playing-raw-pcm-audio-data-coming-from-nsstream/30318859#30318859

Comment: thanks, i will check that!

Comment: I'm not confident enough to flag your question as duplicate, but if you find a solution on your own, don't hesitate to answer your own question.

Comment: As far as i know, there is no way to play RTP directly, so i have to unpack the RTP, catching the data, which is PCM and the PCM can be played by AVFoundation. So this is my Workaround, but anyway +thanks for you help. When i have a working solution i will put it here.

Comment: I know this thread was started almost 3years ago but, lpad do you have any update?